# Splitting string with multiple delimiters in python

Tags: python, string

I have the following string in python:

```
foo = 'a_b_c'
```

How do I split the string into 2 parts: `'a_b'` and `'c'`? I.e, I want to split at the second `'_'`

`str.split('_')` splits into 3 parts: `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`.

Comment: Does `'a_b_c'.rsplit('_', 1)` work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`str.rsplit()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with a limit:

```
part1, part2 = foo.rsplit('_', 1)
```

`str.rsplit()` splits from the right-hand-side, and the limit (second argument) tells it to only split once.

Alternatively, use [`str.rpartition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition):

```
part1, delimiter, part2 = foo.rpartition('_')
```

This includes the delimiter as a return value.

Demo:

```
>>> foo = 'a_b_c'
>>> foo.rsplit('_', 1)
['a_b', 'c']
>>> foo.rpartition('_')
('a_b', '_', 'c')
```

Comment: I'm going to downvote this, because it is a copy of a previous response.

Comment: @AlexReynolds well, this is a poor reason for the downvote. And this answer is not a copy of the comment.

Comment: @AlexReynolds: a comment is *not* a response, nor can I help that someone chose to use a comment. I did not base this answer on the comment. Moreover, my answer includes another alternative *not* mentioned in the comment. I would appreciate voting to happen on the helpfulness of an answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
x = "a_b_c"
print re.split(r"_(?!.*_)",x)
```

You can do it through `re`.Here in `re` with the use of `lookahead` we state that split by `_` after which there should not be `_`.

Comment: Do note that this is overly complicated and and inefficient when you can just use standard methods like `str.rsplit()` and `str.rpartition()`.

Comment: As a general approach, it is a more interesting and broadly applicable solution. +1

Comment: @AlexReynolds: The approach is better covered by the `str.rsplit()` and `str.rpartition()` methods. `str.rsplit()` lets you split more than once, which is harder to do with a regex. The regex is harder to comprehend, so maintenance of the codebase is now more complicated.